# How to run custom Python script on Jupyter Notebook launch (to boot Spark)?

Tags: python, apache-spark, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I found several tutorials on how to configure IPython Notebook to load Spark Context variable `sc` using PySpark (like this one: http://ramhiser.com/2015/02/01/configuring-ipython-notebook-support-for-pyspark/).

The problem is, since now we are using Jupyter Notebook instead of IPython Notebook, we can't create a setup script to load the Spark Context variable like we did with IPython (which should be located in `~/.ipython/profile_pyspark/startup/00-pyspark-setup.py`).

The question is: What are the configurations on Jupyter Notebook that will execute the script `00-pyspark-setup.py` on startup?

Comment: Sounds like you want [Apache Toree](https://github.com/apache/incubator-toree). It takes some effort to setup, though.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

The original answer should still work, but it is unwieldy and we use the following method nowadays that uses PySpark built in variables:

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
```

Then just run PySpark directly like you would normally, but with the above variables set it starts jupyter notebook rather than a shell:

```
cd path/to/spark
bin/pyspark --master local[*]  # Change to use standalone/mesos/yarn master and add any spark config
```

If you start a new notebook you will find Spark set up for you. You can add other options to Juopyter if you want to match your environment, like:

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook --ip='*' --no-browser"
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

You can still set up things with the same initial steps, ie create a profile using `ipython profile create pyspark` and place the startup script in `$(ipython profile locate pyspark)/startup/`.

Next, to make it available in Jupyter notebooks you have to specify a kernel that uses that profile, by creating a file `$(ipython locate)/kernels/pyspark/kernel.json`. This is what mine looks like:

```
{
  "display_name": "PySpark",
  "language": "python",
  "argv": [
    "python",
    "-m", "ipykernel",
    "--profile=pyspark",
    "-f", "{connection_file}"
  ],
  "env": {
    "PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS": " --master spark://localhost:7077 --conf spark.driver.memory=20000m  --conf spark.executor.memory=20000m"
  }
}
```

The important bit is in the `argv` section. The information in the `env` section is picked up by the startup script I use:

```py
import os
import sys

spark_home = '/opt/spark/'
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = spark_home
sys.path.insert(0, spark_home + "/python")
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(spark_home, 'python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip'))

pyspark_submit_args = os.environ.get("PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS", "")
pyspark_submit_args += " pyspark-shell"
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = pyspark_submit_args

filename = os.path.join(spark_home, 'python/pyspark/shell.py')
exec(compile(open(filename, "rb").read(), filename, 'exec'))
```

As you can see it is quite similar to the one you linked, just plus the arguments that are defined in the kernel, and addition of `pyspark-shell` argument which is needed in latest version of PySpark.

Whit this, you can run `jupyter notebook`, open the main page in a browser and you can now create notebooks using this new kernel:

[image: create new pyspark notebook]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @sgvd, I think we are close. I indeed created the kernel, and now, my Jupyter Notebook is showing the PySpark new notebook. But once my notebook created (with kernel PySpark,) executing `sc` returns an empty string... (which means Spark is not loaded) The only changes I made to your script was changing the `spark_home` location and the py4j version. I didn't change `kernel.json` (maybe I should, especially `{connection_file}`?)

Comment: Which version of Spark are you using? This works for me at least for 1.6.x. Also make sure you're using the correct master URL. The one in my answer, `spark://localhost:7077` is for a Spark standalone cluster with the master running on the same machine as Jupyter. If you use Mesos or Yarn, have your master run somewhere else, or your master doesn't listen on `localhost` you have to change this.

Comment: Hey @sgvd. I think I'm at the same step as @htaidirt. However, when I create a PySpark notebook, I get a java error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing application resource.` Do you have any insight on this?